# How use font forge to generate a font in cmd

Tags: c#, fonts, webforms, cmd

prompt please how to convert the ttf to svg  in the utility fontforge from the command line windows, or how use api in .NET, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a script with these two [function calls](http://fontforge.org/scripting-alpha.html):

```
Open($1,1)
Generate($2)
```

and [running](http://fontforge.org/cliargs.html) it like this:

```
fontforge -script script.pe input.ttf output.svg
```

should do what you want.